# How do I SELECT from 3 different Wordpress Tables to find result?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a SELECT statement that pulls data from one table:

```
SELECT user_id, user_email, product_id, download_count  
FROM l3x_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
```

but using the `user_id` I need to find the `group_id` from another  table

and using the `group_id` then get the group name (name) from a third table.

so have this:

```
SELECT r1.user_id, r1.user_email, r1.product_id, r1.download_count, r2.group_id, r3.name 
FROM l3x_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions r1
, l3x_groups_user_group r2
, l3x_groups_group r3
```

but i dont think the 2nd and 3rd table data is usable as it is not associated with user id.

**How do i join (JOIN?) the 3 tables together to get group name?**

Comment: Use explicit join and your old style beginning isn't even complete. Google

Comment: First find out what the association would be (4th table?)

Comment: i would love to ask google (and have many many times) but i don't know what the question is. I don't understand whether JOIN just says 'if this table has this field and this table does too, then just show the rows which have both fields' or if it can do: 'if this table has this field and a second table has this field then give me the result of another field in the 2nd table' - which is what i am trying  to do.

Answer (score 1):

if the tables are set up so that r2 contains user_id and associated group_id and r3 is set up similarly you can

use join

```
SELECT r1.user_id, r1.user_email, r1.product_id, r1.download_count, r2.group_id, r3.name, r3.group_name 
FROM l3x_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions r1   
JOIN l3x_groups_user_group r2
     ON r1.user_id = r2.user_id 
JOIN l3x_groups_group r3 
     ON r2.group_id = r3.group_name
```

Comment: Thank you  so much for replying  so quickly. 
What i need to get out of this is r3.name (as well as r1.user_id, r1.product_id, r1.download_count. but i have these).

Does JOINing  do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pick a field in each table that is shared.

I'd assume r1.group_id=r2.group_id and r2.name=r3.name. In your case, the fields in r1/r2 may have different names than in r2/r3s. You also might have to join using a different field than these. I don't know without knowing all the fields in each table.

You'll then JOIN ON those common fields.

So you'll use somthing like

```
SELECT r1.user_id, r1.user_email, r1.product_id, r1.download_count, r2.group_id, r3.name 
FROM ((l3x_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions r1
LEFT JOIN l3x_groups_user_group r2 ON r1.group_id=r2.group_id)
LEFT JOIN l3x_groups_group r3 ON r2.name=r3.name)
```

If you give a list of the fields in all 3 tables, I can give a more specific answer, but this is the form of the query you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying  so quickly. 
l3x_groups_user_group has 2 fields: user_id, group_id
l3x_groups_group has 6 fields including: group_id, name.

r1 does not have a group _id so i can't: LEFT JOIN l3x_groups_user_group r2 ON r1.group_id=r2.group_id
similarly there is no r2.name.

what i need to get out of this is r3.name (as well as r1.user_id, r1.product_id, r1.download_count. but i have these).

Does JOINing  do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  for all your help. This seems to be working:

```
SELECT r1.user_id, r1.product_id, r1.download_count, r2.group_id, r3.name
FROM l3x_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions r1
JOIN l3x_groups_user_group r2 ON r1.user_id = r2.user_id
JOIN l3x_groups_group r3 ON r2.group_id = r3.group_id
WHERE r1.download_count > 0  AND r2.group_id != 1
```